# Вариант tabs с привязыванем по id

Tags: jquery, tabs

Подскажите вариант для tabs с привязкой контента для кнопки, по клику по которой он вызывается с персонализированным id.

Я использую в данный момент следующий скрипт:

```
<div class="tabs_block">
    <div class="tabs">
        <span class="tab">Вкладка 1</span>
        <span class="tab">Вкладка 2</span>
        <span class="tab">Вкладка 3</span>
    </div>
    <div class="tab_content">
        <div class="tab_item">Содержимое 1</div>
        <div class="tab_item">Содержимое 2</div>
        <div class="tab_item">Содержимое 3</div>
    </div>
</div>

$(".tab_item").not(":first").hide();
$(".tabs_block .tab").click(function() {
    $(".tabs_block .tab").removeClass("active").eq($(this).index()).addClass("active");
    $(".tab_item").hide().eq($(this).index()).fadeIn()
}).eq(0).addClass("active");
```

А мне нужен код для данной структуры, что бы функционал  не зависило от структуры :

```
<div class="tabs_block">
    <div class="tabs">
        <span id="tab_1" class="tab">Вкладка 1</span>
        <div class ="tabs_popup">
          <span id="tab_2" class="tab">Вкладка 2</span>
          <span id="tab_3" class="tab">Вкладка 3</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="tab_content">
        <div id="tab_1_item" class="tab_item">Содержимое 1</div>
        <div id="tab_2_item" class="tab_item">Содержимое 2</div>
        <div id="tab_3_item" class="tab_item">Содержимое 3</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Что бы к примеру по щелчку на id="tab_1" вылазил контент "tab_1_item" и цифра получается передавалась в скрипте через переменную или ещё каким более правильным способом.

Новая структура, по сути от старой отличается только количеством блоков.

```
<div class="tabs">
        <span id="tab_1" class="tab">эстрадный вокал</span>
        <span id="tab_2" class="tab">джазовый вокал</span>
        <span id="tab_3" class="tab">академический вокал</span>
        <span id="tab_4" class="tab">рок вокал</span>
        <span id="tab_5" class="tab">постановка голоса</span>
        <span id="tab_6" class="tab">сольфеджио</span>
        <span id="tab_7" class="tab">экстрим вокал</span>
        <span id="tab_8" class="tab">оперный вокал</span>
        <div class="tabs_block">
            <div class="tb_head">выбрать другое</div>
            <span id="tab_9" class="tab">Вариант 1</span>
            <span id="tab_10" class="tab">Вариант 2</span>
            <span id="tab_11" class="tab">Вариант 3</span>
            <span id="tab_12" class="tab">Вариант 4</span>
            <span id="tab_13" class="tab">Вариант 5</span>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

если я правильно понял

```
$('.tab').on('click',function(){ //по клику на элемент с class='tab'
    let tabContentId='#'+this.id+'_item'; //формируем переменную из id обрабатываемого элемента
    $('.tab_item').hide(); //сначала скрываем все страницы вкладок
    $(tabContentId).show(); //затем показываем с нужным id
});
```

Comment: Не заработало, они все скрываются по клику на .tab. Наверно ошибка здесь let tabContentId=this.id+'_item';   или здесь  $(tabContentId).show();

Comment: Действительно, была допущена ошибка. Забыл указать селектор id в начале. Исправил, у себя проверил - работает.

Comment: Благодарю, отличный вариант решения моей задачи и всего в 5 строк.

Answer (score 1):

Думаю, это то что вам нужно:

```js
function tabShow(selector) {
  $(".tabs span").removeClass("active");
  $("#tab_" + selector).addClass("active");

  $(".tab_content > div").hide();
  $("#tab_" + selector + `_item`).show();
}
$(function() {
  var tabButton = ".tabs span";
  var hash = location.hash;
  if (hash.match(/#tab/)) {
    var tabActive = hash.slice(-1);
    tabShow(tabActive);
  } else {
    tabShow("1");
  }
  $(tabButton).click(function() {
    var selector = $(this).attr("id").slice(-1);
    tabShow(selector);
  });
});
```

```css
.active{font-weight:bold;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="tabs">
  <span id="tab_1" class="tab">Вкладка 1</span>
  <div class="tabs_block">
    <span id="tab_2" class="tab">Вкладка 2</span>
    <span id="tab_3" class="tab">Вкладка 3</span>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="tab_content">
  <div id="tab_1_item">Содержимое 1</div>
  <div id="tab_2_item">Содержимое 2</div>
  <div id="tab_3_item">Содержимое 3</div>
</div>
```

upd.

```js
function tabShow(selector) {
  $(".tabs span").removeClass("active");
  $("#tab_" + selector).addClass("active");

  $(".tab_content > div").hide();
  $("#tab_" + selector + `_item`).show();
}
$(function() {
  var tabButton = ".tabs span";
  var hash = location.hash;
  if (hash.match(/#tab/)) {
    var tabActive = hash.slice(-1);
    tabShow(tabActive);
  } else {
    tabShow("1");
  }
  $(tabButton).click(function() {
    var selector = $(this).attr("id").slice(-1);
    tabShow(selector);
  });
});
```

```css
.tab_content {border-top: 1px solid black; margin-top: 20px;}
.tabs span {display: block;}
.tb_head {text-decoration: underline; margin: 5px 0;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="tabs">
  <span id="tab_1" class="tab">эстрадный вокал</span>
  <span id="tab_2" class="tab">джазовый вокал</span>
  <span id="tab_3" class="tab">академический вокал</span>
  <span id="tab_4" class="tab">рок вокал</span>
  <span id="tab_5" class="tab">постановка голоса</span>
  <span id="tab_6" class="tab">сольфеджио</span>
  <span id="tab_7" class="tab">экстрим вокал</span>
  <span id="tab_8" class="tab">оперный вокал</span>
  <div class="tabs_block">
    <div class="tb_head">Выбрать другое</div>
    <span id="tab_9" class="tab">Вариант 1</span>
    <span id="tab_10" class="tab">Вариант 2</span>
    <span id="tab_11" class="tab">Вариант 3</span>
    <span id="tab_12" class="tab">Вариант 4</span>
    <span id="tab_13" class="tab">Вариант 5</span>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="tab_content">
  <div id="tab_1_item">Результат: эстрадный вокал</div>
  <div id="tab_2_item">Результат: джазовый вокал</div>
  <div id="tab_3_item">Результат: академический вокал</div>
  <div id="tab_4_item">Результат: рок вокал</div>
  <div id="tab_5_item">Результат: постановка голоса</div>
  <div id="tab_6_item">Результат: сольфеджио</div>
  <div id="tab_7_item">Результат: экстрим вокал</div>
  <div id="tab_8_item">Результат: оперный вокал</div>
  <div id="tab_9_item">Результат: Вариант 1</div>
  <div id="tab_10_item">Результат: Вариант 2</div>
  <div id="tab_11_item">Результат: Вариант 3</div>
  <div id="tab_12_item">Результат: Вариант 4</div>
  <div id="tab_13_item">Результат: Вариант 5</div>
</div>
```

Comment: У меня почему то данный код работает как и мой, т.е. как только доходит до табов, которые внутри блока .tabs_block всё работает неправильно. Возможно конкретно в моей структуре что то не так. Обновил структуру в конце своего обращения.

Comment: Я щёлкнул по выполнить код тут, работает некоректно точно так же как у меня сейчас, работают неправильно кнопки в подпапке, первая выдаёт правильный результат, вторая ничего не выдаёт, все последующие начинают дублировать контент с первой кнопки.

Comment: да, если пощелкать по 3м последним видно как они выдают первые 3 результата <div id="tab_1_item">Результат: эстрадный вокал</div>
  <div id="tab_2_item">Результат: джазовый вокал</div>
  <div id="tab_3_item">Результат: академический вокал</div>